# Python - Accessing subclasses' variables from parent class while calling classmethods

Tags: python, oop, class, static

i'm trying to build sort of a "mini django model" for working with Django and MongoDB without using the norel Django's dist (i don't need ORM access for these...).

So, what i'm trying to do is to mimic the standart behavior or "implementation" of default models of django... that's what i've got so far:

File "models.py" (the base)

```
from django.conf import settings
import pymongo

class Model(object):
    @classmethod
    def db(cls):
        db = pymongo.Connection(settings.MONGODB_CONF['host'], settings.MONGODB_CONF['port'])

    @classmethod
    class objects(object):
        @classmethod
        def all(cls):
            db = Model.db() #Not using yet... not even sure if that's the best way to do it
            print Model.collection
```

File "mongomodels.py" (the implementation)

```
from mongodb import models

class ModelTest1(models.Model):
    database = 'mymongodb'
    collection = 'mymongocollection1'

class ModelTest2(models.Model):
    database = 'mymongodb'
    collection = 'mymongocollection2'
```

File "views.py" (the view)

```
from mongomodels import ModelTest1, ModelTest2

print ModelTest1.objects.all() #Should print 'mymongocollection1'
print ModelTest2.objects.all() #Should print 'mymongocollection2'
```

The problem is that it's not accessing the variables from ModelTest1, but from the original Model... what's wrong??

Answer (score 0):

You must give `objects` some sort of link to class that contains it. Currently, you are just hard-coding it to use `Model()`s atttributes. Because you are not instantiating these classes, you will either have to use either a decorator or a metaclass to create the `object` class for you in each subclass of `Model()`.

Comment: Actually what i've got so far was result of trial and error basically, so i'm not very familiar with "decorators" and "metaclasses"... how they would help me here? I'm studying right now about them... XD